# Get All Users of Google Apps Account Using PHP Client Library

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

I'm currently trying to get a list of all users inside the domain and the logic I'm using is the following:

```
$service = new Google_Service_Directory($client);

$optParams = array(
    'customer' => 'my_customer',
    'maxResults' => 500,
    'orderBy' => 'email',
    );

$results = $service->users->listUsers($optParams);
$users = $results->getUsers();

    foreach($users as $user) {
    $usersemails = $user->getPrimaryEmail();
    echo $usersemails.'<br>';
   }
```

The problem is I only get a max of 500 users. I figure out that I have to use the next page token so I tried this:

```
$service = new Google_Service_Directory($client);

$optParams = array(
  'customer' => 'my_customer',
  'maxResults' => 500,
  'orderBy' => 'email',
  'pageToken' => NULL,
);

$results = $service->users->listUsers($optParams);
$pageToken = $results->getNextPageToken();
$users = $results->getUsers();

while($pageToken); 

  foreach($users as $user) {
    $usersemails = $user->getPrimaryEmail();
    echo $usersemails.'<br>';
}
```

But I'm getting the following message:

> 504 Gateway Time-out. The server didn't respond in time.

Is there a problem with the code I'm using or is this a problem with the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking many times I was able to find out that the problem was that I was not properly writing the code. I have modified my code and now it works fine. In case anybody else goes through the same problem perhaps this might help. This is the final code:

```
$service = new Google_Service_Directory($client);

$pageToken = NULL;
$optParams = array(
  'customer' => 'my_customer'
);

try {
  do {
    if ($pageToken){
    $optParams['pageToken'] = $pageToken;   
  }

$results = $service->users->listUsers($optParams);
$pageToken = $results->getNextPageToken();
$users = $results->getUsers();

foreach($users as $user) {
  $usersemails = $user->getPrimaryEmail();
  echo $usersemails.'<br>';
}

} while($pageToken); 

} catch (Exception $e) {
    print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```